# How does the size of deque affect the training speed of a Tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deque

I've ran exactly the same python script with a tensorflow model multiple times. There is only one difference. One half of the scripts uses a deque of size 500000 and the other half one of 1000000 as experience storage. From the storage a batch of 512 randomly picked examples are chosen to train.

The networks are still training, but those with a deque of 500k are about 10% faster so far. Looks like the distance is growing. Sure picking 512 randomly out of a bigger memory might takes a little longer. But 10% over the complete training process?

The code looks like this

```
...
self.memory = deque(maxlen=1000000)
...
def experience_replay(self):
        if len(self.memory) < 512:
            return
        batch = random.sample(self.memory, 512)
        state_batch = np.zeros((512, 6, 7, 2))
        q_values_batch = np.zeros((512, 7))
        idx = 0
        for state, action, reward, state_next, terminal in batch:
            q_update = reward
            if not terminal:
                state_next = np.expand_dims(state_next, axis=0)
                q_update = (reward + 0.95 * np.amax(self.model.predict(state_next)[0]))
            state = np.expand_dims(state, axis=0)
            q_values = self.model.predict(state)
            q_values[0][action] = q_update
            state_batch[idx, ...] = state
            q_values_batch[idx, ...] = q_values
            idx = idx + 1

        self.model.fit(state_batch, q_values_batch, verbose=0)
        self.exploration_rate *= 0.9998
        self.exploration_rate = max(0.01, self.exploration_rate)
```

What could cause this speedup?

Comment: Is this recognition training, or something else ? Maybe the extract of 512 from the bigger set is slightly more diverse ? You run the same loop, so it appearently takes more training cycles.That indicates a set with more, or more diverse variability. A more difficult set to train a match for.

Comment: @Goodies yeah but thats something different. It shouldn't matter how long it takes to train. I'm not interested in the performance of the network. My concerns are about why one loop takes 10% more time just because of one memory element. But I agree, picking 512 out of the bigger set will take longer.

Comment: I don't know your data :) "taking longer" is not what I meant. The move in memory to copy a training pattern does not take relevant time, that is true. But when the pick of 512 from 1M items yields e.g. 200 unique item values and a pick of 512 from 500k yields e.g. only 180 unique item values.. your learning will have to do 10% more work, because there is 10% more entropy in your input. E.g. a broader set of "features" to classify.

Comment: @GoodiesI'm not sure if I got it right this time :). Does it matter that there is more entropy? The algorithm needs maybe 1ms to pick 512 out of 500k or lets say 2ms to pick 512 out of 1M. For the rest of the script 1 second is needed in both cases. Where is the more work in this case? I only got the picking. The rest is just applying the same math over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, *deque()* and *random.sample()* don't work together efficiently.  A *deque* is fast for access near the end-points but is O(n) for indexed lookups in the middle.  This is problematic because *random.sample()* makes repeated, indexed lookups into the deque.  The code fragment shown in the question would be better-off with a list.

The precise answer to your original question is extracting *k* samples from an *n* length deque takes time proportional to `k * n / 4`.  Algorithmically, doubling the size typically doubles the expected value for running time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A list? I used deque because I thought that is somehow efficient to store 500k-1M entries. Creating an empty list and appending entries makes it really better suited for this task and dimensions?

Comment: @Mr.Sh4nnon Both a list and a deque are space-efficient.  The superpower for a deque is the ability to quickly append or pop on the left side as well as the right -- that makes them ideal for FIFO queues.  The superpower for lists is random access indexing -- that makes them ideal for use with *random.sample()*.